# Get Select Tag option Index in Node.js/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express

When submitting a POST request with a form in Node.js/Express

E.g.,

```
<select name="selectname">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

The value that is passed to req.body.selectname is "Value 2" --- however is there a way to tell the form to pass the value "value2" instead?

Edit:

value2 ***is*** the default sent. You may get "Value 2" if your value attributes are not correctly set such as the following:

```
<select name="selectname">
  <option>Value 1</option> 
  <option selected>Value 2</option>
  <option>Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Forms pass the value attribute. If you want the text passed, you'll have to send that as the value instead.

Comment: You say that, but the text is being passed... because I have no value attribute in my actual code. (I swore it was there a second ago) Thanks!

Comment: You want the form to send the selected value on change?

Comment: @developerbh --- No, what ended up happening is that I was confident my HTML code looked like the example above and when I submitted the request I was receiving "Value 2" --- instead of "value2". I was only receiving "Value 2" because I had `<option selected> Value 2</option>` instead of `<option value="value2" selected> Value 2</option>`

Comment: @CodyG. Definitely there's something wrong with the implementation in your node code .. it should take the value not the context

Comment: @developerbh  The form sends the context if you don't have any value attribute! I figured that out since Sterling Archer mentioned that they by default pass the value attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I submitted the request I was receiving "Value 2" --- instead of "value2".

I was only receiving "Value 2" because I had

```
<option selected> Value 2</option>
```

instead of

```
<option value="value2" selected> Value 2</option>
```